# Can't make the Window of my Activity translucent

Tags: android, user-interface, translucency

I'm trying to make my `Activity` translucent, i.e. see-through, but it's not working. It's always opaque. That's my code so far:

```
public class SvetlinTranslucentActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
        w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        w.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0x00FF0000));
    }
}
```

I've been looking at the code from the official API demos but still no success.

Comment: Have you looked at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html ?
The method setBackgroundDrawable says how to make it transparent

Comment: Um. That's what I'm doing, isn't it?!

Comment: Try with ColorDrawable(0) or ColorDrawable(null)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Transparent Activity in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Comment: Works now. Used the answer from [How to create Transparent Activity in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `android:background` in my layout

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:background="#D0000000">
```

and its certainly see through, I can see the other activity below it.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the AndroidManifest.xml, look for the target activity, and set: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"`